# Dynamically changing JS

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, upload

I am making an HTML page and I am using Javascript with JQuery. I will have a map that looks like this:

```
var images = {
'Abstract' : 'http://i.imgur.com/MFkuQ.jpg',
'Animals' : 'http://i.imgur.com/QEt72.png',
'Beach' : 'http://i.imgur.com/nmrqv.jpg',
'Bad sky' : 'http://i.imgur.com/zoO2M.png',
'Colors' : 'http://i.imgur.com/bA718.png',
'Desert' : 'http://i.imgur.com/xvyzD.jpg',
'Dog no background' : 'http://i.imgur.com/k023O.png',
'Dog' : 'http://i.imgur.com/3c5EB.png',
'Gold' : 'http://i.imgur.com/jz4XX.png',
'Island' : 'http://i.imgur.com/7JXt7.jpg',
'Meteor' : 'http://i.imgur.com/iISwt.png',
'Ocean' : 'http://i.imgur.com/i8sy2.jpg',
'Rain' : 'http://i.imgur.com/V82Tb.png',
'Sky' : 'http://i.imgur.com/CMqv2.jpg',
'Textures' : 'http://i.imgur.com/lFKPp.jpg',
'Volcano' : 'http://i.imgur.com/7uy15.png'
}
```

for listing the art I made.  However, I will also be making new art and need to have this map dynamically change. I have tried Mediafire, Pastebin, and several other websites, but they either don't allow you to edit your files, can't generate a link (like http://www.websitename.com/images.js), or get rid of your file after a while. Is there a good website I could upload my file to, and then edit it?

Comment: How about github? Btw, if you have a place to host html - why don't you host js there as well?

Comment: githubs gists might be working.

Comment: Ok, I'll try github. And I will be sending this HTML file by email, not hosting it.

Comment: Now how to I get a plain text file of this? I don't want something like https://gist.github.com/b25dff23c2c4b4bd425a, I want something like https://gist.github.com/b25dff23c2c4b4bd425a.js with just the text so I can use it in my HTML.

Comment: https://raw.github.com/gist/b25dff23c2c4b4bd425a/c485e4c6c1f161ed530a5b9ad7714ad8dd2e390d/images.js

Comment: thank you! um... you might want to post an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: You can also make a github account for free and host the files there. That has the advantage of grouping them all in one place and making them easier to manage. You can also use git to synchronize the files locally and edit them on your machine (with either gists or a github repository).

Comment: Wait. When I edit my github gists the URL for the raw code changes!

Comment: help! (comment not too short)

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob: use github repository, not github gist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host it somewhere, or use a github repository.